# SonarQube unit tests w/o binaries

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

After endless googling and reading tons of documentations, I am completely finsihed.

I want to import already created unit tests reports like .xml and .exec-files (JUnit and Jacoco) into SonarQube. The Problem is

```
Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor...
15:54:48 15:54:48.909 INFO  - No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
15:54:48 15:54:48.909 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 374 ms
15:54:48 15:54:48.909 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
15:54:48 15:54:48.910 INFO  - No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
15:54:48 15:54:48.910 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 1 ms
```

As we have a rather large code, we do not have allways binaries of the src. So, the question is: "How can I import only the finished reports into SonarQube without having binaries?"

SonarRunner Properties

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.core.coveragePlugin=Jacoco
sonar.junit.reportsPath=[...]/workspace/junit/xml-results
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=[...]/workspace/junit/junit-test.exec
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here, the jacoco sensor seems to specifically require the binaries, which makes this unlikely to work: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-jacoco/src/test/java/org/sonar/plugins/jacoco/JaCoCoSensorTest.java

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem migrating from sonarQube 3.7 to sonarQube 4.5. I changed the deprecated sonar.binaries for sonar.java.binaries... And suddenly my coverage didn't work anymore. . 
I had to revert:

```
MyProject.sonar.java.binaries=classes
```

for:

```
MyProject.sonar.binaries=classes
```

and that work for me, even sonar tells me that I'm using deprecated entries.

Comment: It says *As we have a rather large code, we do not have allways binaries of the src. So, the question is: "How can I import only the finished reports into SonarQube without having binaries?"*. The key word is **without** binaries.